# How to check the root cause of CUDA out of memory issue in the middle of training?

Tags: gpu, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm running roberta on huggingface `language_modeling.py`. After doing 400 steps I suddenly get a CUDA out of memory issue. Don't know how to deal with it. Can you please help? Thanks

Comment: Which version of `transformers` are you running? Also, please include the parameters you're running the model with, including your available hardware.

Comment: Already solved it, but thank you for the help ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I didn't check the size of my GPU memory with comparison to the sizes of samples. I had a lot of pretty small samples and after many iterations a large one. My bad.
Thank you and remember to check these things if it happens to you to.

Answer (score 2):

This can have multiple reasons. If you only get it after a few iterations, it might be that you don't free the computational graphs. Do you use `loss.backward(retain_graph=True)` or something similar?

Also, when you're running inference, be sure to use

```
with torch.no_grad():
    model.forward(...)
```

Otherwise the computational graphs are saved there as well and potentially never freed since you never call `backward()` on them.